# python subprocess.check_call is not raising exceptions for failed calls on linux within RPC process

Tags: python, linux, error-handling, subprocess

EDIT: adding that this problem seems to be strictly related to making these calls from within an RPC process to the title.  I thought I was going to be required to use RPC to do what I was doing but was mistaken.
After pulling my code out of that process and running from the server it works as expected.  I have decided to leave the question rather than delete it in case anyone else might find the comments of use.

Just as the title suggests, CalledProcessError is not triggering my except block when a subprocess check_call fails.

My code is fairly straight forward, I have a UNC path that I want to mount to a local directory.  if it does not exist, we create it and mount it.  we then push export_file to a subdirectory on the mounted share (that we create if needed).  If any of these operations fail we want to log it and fail out.  Finally, we unmount the share.

I attempted making one call using '&&' separators but this only seemed to convolute things when things went wrong.  After separating all the operations into their own calls using subprocess.check_call() I am getting the results I want for known good situations, the problem is that I want to re-use this code as a test for mountability by setting export_file=None

The code is as follows:

```
def export_backup(local_dir, remote_dir, creds, export_file=None):
    """
    process for testing UNC path mountability and for exporting file to UNC path
    :param local_dir: path for local dir to be used as mount point
    :param remote_dir: UNC for remote path to mount to local dir
    :param creds: dictionary with keys: 'username', 'domain', and 'password' (set value to None if non-existent)
    :param export_file: path to file for exporting, set to None to simply test mountability of remote_dir
    """
    try:
        # in case we failed to unmount for whatever reason
        if os.path.ismount(local_dir):
            # unmount existing mount
            subprocess.check_call(['sudo', 'umount', '-l', local_dir])
        elif not os.path.isdir(local_dir):
            # create new directory
            subprocess.check_call(['sudo', 'mkdir', local_dir])
        # mount path
        cmd = ['sudo', 'mount', '-t', 'cifs']
        # build creds
        cred_string = ','.join(['{0}={1}'.format(key, value) for (key, value) in creds.items() if value])
        if cred_string:
            cmd.extend(['-o', cred_string])
        cmd.extend([remote_dir, local_dir])
        subprocess.check_call(cmd)
        if export_file:
            export_dir = os.path.join(local_dir, '{0}-appl-export'.format(gethostname()))
            new_file_name = os.path.join(export_dir, os.path.basename(export_file))
            if not os.path.isdir(export_dir):
                # create subdirectory
                subprocess.check_call(['sudo', 'mkdir', export_dir])
            # export file
            subprocess.check_call(['sudo', 'cp', export_file, new_file_name])
    except Exception as ex:
        logger.exception(u'appliance.rpc.export_backup.error', cause=ex)
        raise ex
    finally:
        # unmount
        subprocess.check_call(['sudo', 'umount', '-l', local_dir])
```

I can make my own checks for if operations have actually succeeded or failed by making calls like:

```
if not os.path.ismount(local_dir):
    raise Exception('Failed to mount')
```

After running my subprocess commands... and this works, but this seems broken and backwards.

From everything that I have read (and even tested in python shells), check_call should raise a CalledProcessError if something exits with a non-zero return code, but for some reason I cannot understand they are not triggering for me here.

an example of a 'bad call' I have tried would be

```
subprocess.check_call(['sudo', 'mount', '-t', 'cifs', '-o', 'username=somethingbad,password=somethingwrong,domain=thisisrightforsomereason', '//destination/doesnt/exist', '/mnt/export'])
```

from the shell this tells me: 'could not resolve address for destination: Unknown error' and then feeds me the CalledProcessError traceback.  But when I feed those same creds into my function it appears to have succeeded.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: put `subprocess.check_call('exit 1', shell=True)` before any `check_call()` that you think should fail and update your questions with the results.

Comment: setting shell to True did not seem to work.  I am making these calls from an rpc process... does that make a difference?

Comment: It is not about `shell=True`. Put the code *exactly* as I've written it and report the results.

Comment: Fortunately, I was able to solve this by removing the constraint I thought I had of running it within the rpc process.  When I pulled the code out and ran it on the server itself it worked as expected.
Unfortunately, after the refactor, I am no longer a position to test the functionality of your comment exactly as written.  Apologies @J.F.Sebastian, Thank you for your help anyway!